# Javascript - use of indexOf to search for strings

Tags: javascript

In the first block, I make sure the password does not contain 'password'.  It works perfectly.

```
  var element=document.getElementById('password');
  if (element.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('password') > -1){ //returns 0 or more if present
    alert('Password may not contain the word `password`.');
    element.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

In the second block I check that the password does not containthe firstname, it does not work, what have I done wrong?

```
  //stop password of firstname
  var element=document.getElementById('password');
  var firstname=document.getElementById('firstname');
  if (element.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(firstname.value) > -1){ //returns 0 or more if present
    alert('Password may not contain the firstname.');
    element.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Have you forgotten a .toLowerCase() on firstname.value, and then the test fails because of differences in casing?

Comment: yes that was the problem, thanks

Comment: -2 for being blind??  really??  I've made the same mistakes in my 20 year career many times.  Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes.  Now that I'm over 40, I need the second set of eyes for a different reason... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to lowercase the first name:

```
// stop password of firstname
var element = document.getElementById('password');
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
if(element.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(firstname.value.toLowerCase()) > -1) { //returns 0 or more if present
    alert('Password may not contain the firstname.');
    element.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (element.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(firstname.value.**toLowerCase()**) > -1)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's not the question but you can do the same thing in a really easy and expressive way using [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string):

```
_.includes(element.value.toLowerCase(), firstname.value.toLowerCase())
```